# Using SUMPRODUCT on column found by lookup

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a sheet which has the following properties where Column A is item name, and Column B is item build price (computed).

[image]

I have second sheet which has the build information for the items, which has 1st column is the components, 2nd is the price per component, and each column after is the quantity of components needed to make item which is named in row 1

[image]

What I am wanting to do is to in sheet 1 have the calculated cost to make in column C.  I tried doing various sumproducts formulas, like

```
=SUMPRODUCT((BlueprintInfo!B:B)*(BlueprintInfo!C:BB)*(BlueprintInfo!C1:BB1=A3))
```

but it either doesn't work OR I get excel ran out of resources.  Any ideas how to make this work?

thanks

Comment: Just to check, should the formula incorporate the 1s in `C2:E2` on the second sheet?

Comment: ultimately the "1" in the c2:e2 is going to be used as a divisor on the cost, since not all items build 1 unit when they are made, some make more.  However, I can do that via a lookup if needed.

Comment: Are the numbers representative? For example, should the material cost to produce item A be $28,136.24: ($3.65 * 3556 + $1.52 * 3158 + $12.52 * 9 + $512.20 * 20)?

Comment: Yes and no.  I made up the "Sell Price" on the 1st sheet, but yes, you have the basic of what I want.  For item A it should be the sumproduct of sheet2's B and C.  For item B, it would be sumproduct of sheet2's B and D, etc...

Comment: Got it, that's what I figured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an `INDEX`/`MATCH` within your `SUMPRODUCT`. Adjust the ranges as needed.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(BlueprintInfo!$B$3:$B$6,INDEX(BlueprintInfo!$C$3:$E$6,,MATCH(A2,BlueprintInfo!$C$1:$E$1,0)))
```

- The `MATCH` matches the Item Name in `A2` within the range `BlueprintInfo!$C$1:$E$1`, returning 1 in this case.
- Then use this as the column reference: in this case effectively `INDEX(BlueprintInfo!$C$3:$E$6,,1)`, which is just `BlueprintInfo!$C$3:$C$6`.

This is the same as

```
=SUMPRODUCT(BlueprintInfo!$B$3:$B$6,BlueprintInfo!$C$3:$C$6)
```

which is what you'd use if you hard-coded Column `C` for Item A.

[image]